# Sorting data to get size, mean and SD for each group in R

Tags: r

A small sample of the data is shown below. Please consider I have more columns

```
 dat<-read.table (text=" id Tall1    Group1  Tall2   Group2  Tall3   Group3  Tall4   Group4
  1  25  M   24  M   23  N   33  N
  2  34  N   16  M   23  M   43  N
  3  41  N   20  M   44  N   60  N
  4  25  M   24  N   44  N   55  M
   5 26  N   12  N   44  M   90  M
    ", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get the following table

```
NoM MeanM   SDM NoN MeanN   SDN
2   25  0   3   33.66   7.5
3   20  4   2   18  8.45
2   33.5    14.48   3   37  12.12
2   72.5    24.74   3   45.33   13.65
```

I want to get N, mean and SD for each group according to their Talls, i.e.,  Tall1 with Group1, Tall2 with Group2 and...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I couldn't think of a good way to get the pairs of columns together, so had to kind of force it.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat_value<-dat %>% select(contains("Tall")) %>% pivot_longer(cols=1:4,names_to = "category",values_to="values")

dat_group<-dat %>% select(contains("Group")) %>% pivot_longer(cols=1:4,names_to = "category",values_to="group") %>%
  select(group)

new_dat<-dat_value %>%
  bind_cols(dat_group) %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  summarize(NoM=sum(group=="M"),
            MeanM=mean(values[group=="M"]),
            SDM=sd(values[group=="M"]),
            NoN=sum(group=="N"),
            MeanN=mean(values[group=="N"]),
            SDN=sd(values[group=="N"])
            ) %>%
  ungroup()

new_dat
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>   category   NoM MeanM   SDM   NoN MeanN   SDN
#>   <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Tall1        2  25     0       3  33.7  7.51
#> 2 Tall2        3  20     4       2  18    8.49
#> 3 Tall3        2  33.5  14.8     3  37   12.1 
#> 4 Tall4        2  72.5  24.7     3  45.3 13.7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = matches("Tall|Group"), names_to = c(".value", "key"), names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]*)(\\d+)$") %>% 
    group_by(key, Group) %>% 
    summarise(No=n(), Mean = mean(Tall), SD = sd(Tall), .groups = "drop") %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = c(No, Mean, SD), names_sep = "")

# A tibble: 4 × 7
  key     NoM   NoN MeanM MeanN   SDM   SDN
  <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1         2     3  25    33.7   0    7.51
2 2         3     2  20    18     4    8.49
3 3         2     3  33.5  37    14.8 12.1 
4 4         2     3  72.5  45.3  24.7 13.7
```

Comment: For large data, they are not based on rows they are mixed. Can we do better?

Comment: @user330 Sorry I do not understand you. What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you, for example, when the number of columns is increased, you will get the results for row 4 in row 8. the results are not matched with raws results.

Comment: @user330 May you modify your data example (and accordingly the output) increasing the number of columns, so it happens what you say? Then, I will be able to contrast your desired output with the result of my code, and then I will try to do better.

Comment: Thanks, I have a large database, sorry. I have added IDs to the data. So I want to see the outcome according to IDs. So, in Id=40, I can exactly see NO, mean and Sd.

Comment: @user330 I do not understand yet. Rows in the final table do not correspond to id's. For example, for first row, NoM = 2 because id's 1 and 4 have Tall1 = M, while NoN = 3 because id's 2,3 and 5 have Tall1 = N. I have updated the answer to deal with other columns like Id and to keep the end value of the variables `Tall`, `Group` 1,2,3,...